# Completion with wildcards in directory names in bash

Tags: bash, wildcards, autocomplete

I can do:

```
$ cd sources/ar #[TAB] here would complete word 'ar' to 'art'
```

I can do

```
$ cd */art #[enter] here would bring me to sources/art
```

I can do

```
$ cd */art #[TAB] that would expand */art to sources/art in command-line
```

I want to do

```
$ cd */a #[TAB] to complete to '*/art' or to 'sources/art'.
```

Is there any way to enable that in bash?

Comment: Is `exec zsh` an acceptable answer?