# bash custom tab completion with wildcards

Tags: bash, wildcards, autocomplete

I have a script (let's call it `myscript`) and I want to enable autocomplete arguments for files with a specific extension (e.g. `.txt`). I can do this simply with:

```
complete -f -X '!*.txt' myscript
```

Then, given the files `a`, `b`, `a.txt`, `b.txt`, and `ab.txt` typing "myscript" and hitting tab twice gives me:

```
$ myscript
a.txt  ab.txt  b.txt
```

What I want to do is allow wildcards to filter this further, e.g. if I type "myscript *b*" and hit tab twice I want to see:

```
$ myscript *b*
ab.txt  b.txt
```

Unfortunately this doesn't give me any autocompletion. If I remove the custom autocomplete (or pass `-o bashdefault` to `complete`) it gives me:

```
$ myscript *b*
ab.txt  b  b.txt
```

I don't want to see `b` in the results or have it passed to the script if I hit enter. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: This is a general problem with bash custom completion (we've had the same question [about `cd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296639/completion-with-wildcards-in-directory-names-in-bash) several times, unanswered so far). It works in zsh.